# Can't import rows in PGSQL with NPGSql in .Net core app with BeginTextImport / TEXT COPY

Tags: .net, postgresql, npgsql

I am using NPGSql driver (version 3.2.0) in a .Net core console app. As I have to insert a large number of rows I would like to use the COPY method but I always get these errors in the postgresql log files:

```
STATEMENT:  COPY events FROM STDIN WITH DELIMITER AS '  ' NULL AS ''
ERROR:  COPY from stdin failed: 
CONTEXT:  COPY events, line 52
```

The line number seems to be often 1 but seems to be random (I get 89, 52, etc.) whereas I have only 26 columns. I am not sure how this line number is calculated by PGSQL.

The other problem is that while I did try/catch the whole code block, at no point an exception is thrown by npgsql and my foreach loop goes on for the millions of rows I am importing. I also tried to write into a single StringBuilder and make a single Write() operation but the result is pretty the same : Not a single row is ever imported in PGSQL and I get the same logs than above.

A simplified version of the code is below (I have actually 26 columns to be inserted with only string, bool, datetime and int)

```
pgWriter = pgCnx.BeginTextImport("COPY events FROM STDIN WITH DELIMITER AS '\t' NULL AS ''");

foreach (MyObject o in myArray)
{
   pgWriter.Write("{0}\t", o.b ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
   pgWriter.Write("{0}\t", o.dt.ToUniversalTime());

   // last column is a string 
   if (o.filepath == null)
   {
       pgWriter.Write("");   // for null values I leave an empty character
   }
   else
   {
      // Escape string before writing it
      string tmp = o.filepath.Replace("\\", "\\\\");
      pgWriter.Write("{0}", tmp);
   }

   // Ends our row
   pgWriter.Write("\n");
}
```

PS : I did check the tabs and it seems there is no problem with the string. What annoys me is that NPGsql doesn't catch any exception while the PGSQL clearly seems to be unhappy with what is being sent, is there a way to catch these problems from the C# code?

An another question: Is there a latency between COPY and when the row is available for SELECT query? The fact that I am not seeing any row with the SELECT query after 10s of my loop inserting rows, maybe there is a flush method that I should call or something similar?

Many thanks,

Comment: I can only answer "another question": While `COPY` is running, the transaction is still uncommitted and you cannot see its results. After `COPY` has failed, the transaction is rolled back, and its effects are gone.

Comment: Thanks @LaurenzAlbe is there a way to "commit" or "flush"  a COPY command? Or does it only happen when you close the connection?

Comment: The transaction running the `COPY` must commit itself when it is done (usually right after the statement completed successfully). There is (fortunately) no way for a third party to do that. I think that the correct way to debug your problem would be to log the data lines you are sending to the `COPY` command. Then you should be able to figure out where and why it fails.

Answer (score 1):

First, when doing COPY in text mode (`BeginTextImport`), Npgsql doesn't look at your input or interact with it in any way - it simply pipes it to PostgreSQL. If there are any errors with it, PostgreSQL will be the one throwing the error (as you can see). Npgsql has no business parsing your input and throwing any exceptions in this scenario.

Second, as has been noted in the comments, the entire COPY operation is considered to be a transaction, so any error with any row will cause the entire operation to be rolled back, and no rows will be committed.

Third, rather than formatting your data in text format and having to worry about escaping and other text-related issues, why not simply use binary COPY ([see the docs](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html))? In binary COPY you tell Npgsql to import strings, ints, etc. and it takes the responsibility of encoding those values in the PostgreSQL binary format. Aside from binary being faster than text, it allows you to avoid all formatting/escaping-related issues.

Basically the only reason to use text COPY is if you already have data files that are properly formatted and ready for import into PostgreSQL more or less as-is (e.g. generated by some program). If your importing program knows about the values, it's better to do binary.